# The right way to implement a progressbar in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm learning winforms and I have set myself a simple goal of making a progressbar that goes from empty to full. Here's my misshapen attempt:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
        {
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the `Thread.Sleep()` is reprehensible. How do I avoid it here?

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168192/progressbar-separate-thread). Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946377/c-progressbar-problem). Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336553/how-to-display-progressbar-if-waithandle-is-used).

Comment: Or if you want to do something excited try to Run an Algorithm and use StopWatch object to Measure a Step from that Algorithm ,than you can calculate how many times the Step will be performed so you can get TotalTime ,and based on that Use you're math skills to get Percentage of the Current Stage ,so i think that will satisfy you're teacher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are already doing it almost right. The `BackgroundWorker` has a built in mechanism for reporting progress already.

```
public Form1()
{
    bw1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw1.ProgressChanged += bw1_ProgressChanged;
    bw1.DoWork += bw1_DoWork;

    bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    while (workNotDone)
    {
        //Do whatever work
        worker.ReportProgress(CalculateProgressDonePercentage());
    }
}

private void bw1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //This is called on GUI/main thread, so you can access the controls properly
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Unless of course you're just trying to animate a progress bar without actually reporting any progress, in which case you should probably just use the `Marquee` type that will automatically scroll a progressbar without doing anything. Or just use a background thread with `Thread.Sleep()`.

Answer (score 3):

In a background thread, there is nothing wrong with calling `Thread.Sleep`.
If this is a placeholder, you can safely replace that with actual work.

However, you cannot manipulate the ProgressBar (or any other control) directly from the background thread.
Instead, you should use the `BackgroundWorker`'s built-in progress features to control the progress bar.

If you're just trying to animate a meaningless progressbasr, you should use a WinForms `Timer` instead of the `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to test updating the UI while doing a time-comsuming task, `Thread.Sleep` is ok. For non-trivial programs, you will always find some task to do here instead.

However, you should not update the progress bar directly inside `BackgroundWorker.DoWork`, as Windows requires that updating UI must be called on the UI thread, not the background one. Instead, call `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method. Always update the UI inside `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event.

You couls see the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx